# what can cause `rails s` to ignore the -e switch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm seeing some strange behavior when I run Rails server with `rails s -e [env]` (double ** added for emphasis):

```
~/app> rails s -e=**production**# << ok...v
=> Booting Mongrel              #         v huh?
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in **test** on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
^CExiting
~/app> rails s -e=**development**  
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in **test** on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
^CExiting
~/app> RAILS_ENV=**development** rails s
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in **development** on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
^CExiting
~/app> RAILS_ENV=**production** rails s
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in **production** on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

The upshot is that the `-e` switch is being ignored.

The [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html) doesn't mention any situations where it will be overriden. The command line help says `-e  Specifies the environment to run this server under  test/development/production).` OK.

I really think this was working fine a few weeks ago (been a while since I started a prod server on that box) so I may have changed something that broke this, but what? I checked for places where I was using `=` instead of `==` but didn't find any. Don't *think* that would explain this.

**Update: John** correctly points out that it is `-e [env]`. I tried that first with the same results then tried `-e=[env]`. The correct way (still produces incorrect result):

```
~/app> rails s -e production -p 5000
=> Booting Mongrel ^^^^^^^^^           vvvv
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in test on http://0.0.0.0:5000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

Comment: It's odd that running rails s on its own brings up the test environment, rather than development, as is the default behavior.  You can try setting the RAILS_ENV environment variable, which is generally respected throughout rails,  and see what happens: `$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you don't have the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable set as it will override whatever you pass as a command line option.

The relevant bit of the [rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb#L54) ydoes this

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= options[:environment]
```

`options` is populated from the command line arguments, so if `RAILS_ENV` is already set your command line options have no effect.

Comment: Ah, it looks like this is the answer. Didn't know that, thanks. I *do* have the RAILS_ENV set, to mimic production.

Answer (score 0):

It's `rails s -e <env>`, not `rails s -e=<env>`. Notice the space between `-e` and the name of the environment:

```
#Ψ rails s -e production
#=> Booting WEBrick                     vvvvvvvvvv
#=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^
#Ψ rails s -e staging
#=> Booting WEBrick                     vvvvvvv
#=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in staging on http://0.0.0.0:3000
                                        ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: 0_o all of it? This is behind IP protection so I can't share it.